# debug facebook canvas app after ssl restriction

Tags: facebook, debugging, ssl, canvas

I have a canvas iframe Facebook app.
I updated the secure canvas URL with https url and it works fine.
since October 1st, it is not allowed to access apps without ssl.
I used to debug my app by creating a duplicate app with localhost as the canvas URL.
Since October 1st (or actually since today...) it is not possible to access it due to the ssl restriction. How can I debug facebook app now??

Comment: Are you asking how to set the domain of your test app to "localhost" and then debug it when the scheme is https? If so I think we need to know something about your test environment (e.g. using VS2010 with the development server).

Answer (score 11):

In your account settings turn off 'Safe browsing' so you will be visiting Facebook without https. Then it does work for me (after turning on Sandbox mode that is).

Answer (score 0):

Turn sandbox on

[image]
<sub>(source: [phpcode.eu](http://phpcode.eu/images/1317828399.png))</sub>

> Apps on Facebook authentication and security migration
>
> All Canvas and Page tab apps must convert to process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate for use in Secure Canvas URL and Secure Page Tab URL **(unless you are in Sandbox mode).**

Comment: it is not helping. even with sandbox mode enabled, Facebbok requires SSL... it gives this message: Secure browsing is not supported
This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS).

Comment: @user980637: It takes a while to save settings. When you press "save" it will show you "it may take a while to proccess your changes to all server"